# Are there any planets or moons denser than Earth?

Tags: exoplanet, density, core, geology, terrestrial-planets

Earth has the highest density out of all planets, planetoids and moons of our planetary system, and also has a higher density than the Sun. Do we know any exoplanets or moons denser than Earth?

Comment: different but related: [How small can a planet be and still have Earth-like gravity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2315/7982) as well as [Is Earth's 1g solid surface gravity unusually high for exoplanets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1930/7982) and also [Are there any known asteroids with average density similar to that of Earth's?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27930/7982) This one may be hard to answer because there aren't likely to be very good ways to determine the masses of exoplanets directly. At least that's my guess.

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for the links.

Comment: Related: [Planets classified by density](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/planets-classification-by-density)

Comment: you say earth has a higher density than that of the sun.... but given that the core is 150g/cm3 (vs earths 5g/cm3) when you say "density" do you mean "average density"?

Comment: @UKMonkey I mean total density, not just the core or other layers. The Earth's core also has a higher density (12.9 g/cm3) than the entire Earth.

Comment: @qqjkztd No, because there are no humans on other planets in this world unless one goes there from Earth. :-)

Comment: Actually, Mercury has a much higher density (13.6 gm/cm3 as opposed to Earth's 5.5 gm/cm3). The planet may even be a remnant core of a much larger planet. Many similar exoplanets are out there, but I'd have to go through the NASA Exoplanet Archive https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=planets to find them. Check out the website, it's awesome with easy to use interactive capabilities.

Comment: @JackR.Woods No, Mercury's density is 5.43 g/cm3 and Venus' is 5.24 g/cm3. While both are close to the Earth's they're not as high or higher. Your value is propably for Mercury's core only.

Comment: @user30007 My mistake, I googled "density of Mercury". I would still say that Mercury has a very high density "for its size" indicating it being a possible "core remnant". Density does have a correlation with size given similar composition, so there must be many super-earths out there with a higher density.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page on [Chthonian planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chthonian_planet):

> Transit-timing variation measurements indicate for example that
> Kepler-52b, Kepler-52c and Kepler-57b have maximum-masses between 30
> and 100 times the mass of Earth (although the actual masses could be
> much lower); with radii about 2 Earth radii, they might have densities
> larger than that of an iron planet of the same size. These exoplanets
> are orbiting very close to their stars and could be the remnant cores
> of evaporated gas giants or brown dwarfs. If cores are massive enough
> they could remain compressed for billions of years despite losing the
> atmospheric mass.

Answer (score 23):

I feel it's a cheap answer but heavy Jupiters can get much denser than Earth because planets with Jupiter's mass stop adding size as they add more mass.   A planet with Jupiter's size and 10-12 times Jupiter's mass would be over twice Earth's density.

As far as Earth-like planets, there's a cool property of terrestrial planets, more mass means more tightly packed in their cores.  Basically a similar effect to the heavy Jupiters but not as pronounced.    If you double the mass and keep the element ratio the same, the density should increase.    For example, a planet like Mercury with a very high iron content, but much greater mass should easily surpass Earth's density.

Kepler 10b, appears to be a super-earth and its estimated density is greater than Earth's at 5.8 ± 0.8 g/cm<sup>3</sup>.  It has a mass of about 3.7 Earths.   The ± 0.8 g/cm<sup>3</sup> offers some room for uncertainty, but some of the more massive terrestrial planets should be more dense than Earth.

I'd take this [list with a grain of salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transiting_exoplanets), but you can sort by density.

[Kepler 131c](http://www.openexoplanetcatalogue.com/planet/Kepler-131%20c/) which you mention appears to be a super Earth but its mass has a high margin for error.  I would add that a mass 8 times that of Earth and a radius smaller than Earth is probably impossible, so I'm highly skeptical of some of those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

From another question on the stack exchange I just found out about an exoplanet with a much higher density than Earth: Kepler-131c.

http://www.exoplanetkyoto.org/exohtml/Kepler-131_c.html

Comment: What density are you seeing there? I see 0.026 $M_J$ and 0.075 $R_J$ and I assume $J$ stands for Jupiter. What density does that work out to?

Comment: @uhoh See userLTK's answer.

Comment: NASA page on Kepler-131c: https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/exoplanet-catalog/5941/kepler-131-c/ . Those numbers correspond to a density of $76.4\text{g}/\text{cm}^3$, or 13.9 times the average density of the Earth. That makes no sense, as noted in [Mass-radius relations and core-envelope decompositions of super-Earths and sub-Neptunes](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/787/2/173). There's something wrong with the reported mass, the reported size, or both. The linked article gives the uncertainty in the mass of Kepler-131c. It's very large.

Comment: @DavidHammen As userLTK said it has a high margin of error.